# How to create a sharepoint dashbord (display screen)

Tags: sharepoint-online, display-form, dashboard

I want to create a dashboard to show data (Currently using a Word document but could use a different type of document if required) to display KPI information in our performance center where stand up meetings take place.

What we doing at the moment is creating a document in Word with the KPI information and sharing that document and saving the link.  We then have a monitor with a Raspberry Pi connected and when the Raspberry Pi boots up it displays the word document in chrome browser.  This works fine apart from when word opens up, the ribbon is taking too much room and its not showing all the information in the document.  How are other people doing this? and how can we remove the ribbon bar from being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the ribbon you can do this with CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
#s4-ribbonrow { display: none; }
</style>
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Where do i remove the css?

Comment: you can add this code into a script editor webpart you can add to your page.

Comment: The word document i shared is directly from a document library.   Is it still possible?